# JavaScript problem: Render part of string in button click not working

Tags: javascript

The problem is:
Change the array ["cakro", "gazar", "faarsi"] to string first by reversing.
1. first reverse each item in array as orkac, razag, israaf.
2. then concatenate from last element and final string would be israafrazagcakro
3. the problem part is to render two letter at once in a click of button.
i.e first render 'is' only then 'ra' only then so on.

My code:

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var fruits = ["cakro", "gazar", "faarsi"];
var first = fruits[0];
var second = fruits[1];
var third = fruits[2];

function reverse(first){
    var splitString = first.split("");
    var reverseArray = splitString.reverse(); 
    var joinArray = reverseArray.join("");
    return joinArray;
    }

var firstr = reverse(first);
var secondr = reverse(second);
var thirdr = reverse(third);
var total = thirdr+secondr+firstr;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = total;
var count = 0;

function nextFunc(total){
        if (count = 0){  //to print 'is'
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = total.substring(0,2);}
        else if (count = 1){  //to print 'ra'
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = total.substring(2,4);}
        else if (count = 2){    //to print 'af'
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = total.substring(4,6);}
        else {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = total.substring(6,8);}        
        count++;
        return (document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML);
}
</script>

<button type = "button" onclick = nextFunc(total) >Go</button>
```

The problem is i can't take the button part inside script part and the value of total is reset every time and the output is `ra` only. But i want the output to iterate on click of button. I want to do it in core JS so please help. Thanks

Comment: = is not comparison.

Comment: Oh,god thanks a ton. is there a shorter way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A more concise way to achieve your result using Array.map() and a for loop:

```
var fruit = ["cakro", "gazar", "faarsi"];

// This maps every word in your array to a new array called reverse where every word has been reversed.
var reversed = fruit.map(word =>word.split("").reverse().join(""));
var word = reversed.join();



function nextFunc(word){
    for(let i=0;i<word.length;i++)
    {
        if(i+1 % 2 === 0) // Every two elements this will be true. 
        {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = word.substring(i-1,i);
        }
   }
}
```

Brief explanation:
We create and transform our original array in one shot using ES6's Array.map() feature. These higher-order array functions are extremely useful. After we generate the array of reversed strings, we create a string using the `join` method. Now all that's left is to rewrite your `nextFunc` function. This time, instead of using consecutive `if else` statements, we can simplify things using the `%` operator. Each loop iteration we check if our current index is a multiple of two, and if it is then we will perform a substring split from our current index (i) and the item directly before it, (i-1).

Array.map() documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: thanks for the shortcut but I guess that is not my solution though. like commas are not included and words must be reversed not a total string and also should render on click of button. Thanks though.

Comment: This solution will reverse each word, and in your answer the var `total` is the concatenation of the three reversed words. Either way, the `Array.map()` function *does* provide the functionality that you'd like to achieve in a much more succinct and standard-practice manner. It's good practice to work with, even if **my** code isn't exactly what you were looking for :)